# Regular expression to convert substring to link

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, regex, string

i need a Regular Expression to convert a a string to a link.i wrote something but it doesnt work in asp.net.i couldnt solve and i am new in Regular Expression.This function converts (bkz: string) to (bkz: show.aspx?td=string)

```
Dim pattern As String = "&lt;bkz[a-z0-9$-$&-&.-.ö-öı-ış-şç-çğ-ğü-ü\s]+)&gt;"
Dim regex As New Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
str = regex.Replace(str, "<a href=""show.aspx?td=$1""><font color=""#CC0000"">$1</font></a>")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp is in trouble because of a ')' without '('

Would:

```
&lt;bkz:\s+((?:.(?!&gt;))+?.)&gt;
```

work better ?

The first group would capture what you are after.

Answer (score 4):

Generic remarks on your code: beside the lack of opening parentheses, you do redundant things: $-$ isn't incorrect but can be simplified into $ only. Same for accented chars.
Everybody will tell you that font tag is deprecated even in plain HTML: favor span with style attribute.

And from your question and the example in the reply, I think the expression could be something like:

```
\(bkz: ([a-z0-9$&.öışçğü\s]+)\)
```

the replace string would look like:

```
(bkz: <a href=""show.aspx?td=$1""><span style=""color: #C00"">$1</span></a>)
```

BUT the first $1 must be actually URL encoded.

Comment: By the way Philho,
 Ur solution works by deleting (bkz:).we see just string as Link between (bkz: and ).it is not problem for now but i wonder what we should do if we wanted to see (bkz:) too?

Comment: @Compiler: Regarding your pattern: I see that you are trying to match (turkish?) text. You should probably use \w in place of your manually selected characters: [\w\s$.]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Vonc,Now it doesnt raise error but also When i assign str to a Label.Text,i cant see the link too.Forexample after i bind str to my label,it should be viewed in view-source ;

```
<span id="Label1">(bkz: <a href="http://www.mysite.com?t=here">here</a>)</span>
```

But now,it is in viewsource source;

```
<span id="Label1">(bkz: here)</span>
```

Comment: I am not sure what is still the problem here... Are you saying the result of regex.replace(str,...) is incorrect ?

Comment: i think,regex.replace doesnt replace.Because after i assign Label1.Text=str,i dont see the link.(i do it in CodeBehind).

Comment: I didnt see there was a ':' after bkz. Could you try my revised regex ? (the one with "bkz:")